# Array of checkboxes give unexpected values at submit event

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to store an array of 9 checkboxes each related to same entity in my database.

Exemple of desired data

```
['0','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'] #Array[]|length = 9
['1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0']
['0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0']
['1','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0']
['2','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0']
['0','2','0','0','0','0','0','0','0']
['0','0','2','0','0','0','0','0','0']
['0','0','2','1','0','0','0','0','0']
['1','0','2','0','0','0','0','0','0']
```

Here that's i've got for these corresponding examples

```
['0','0']
['1','0']
['0','1']
['1','1']
['2','0']
['0','0']
['0','2']
['0','0','2'] #something i cant understand
['1','0','2']
```

I use basic ChoiceType

```
$builder
        ->add('recipe', ChoiceType::class, [
          'choices' => [],
          'multiple' => true,
          'expanded' => true,
          'label' => 'Craft',
        ])
;

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $craft = $event->getData();
        $recipe = $craft['recipe'];

        dump($recipe); # good at this point
});

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $craft = $event->getData();
        $recipe = $craft['recipe'];

        dump($recipe); # bad array...
});
```

Accorded to symfony documentation, between these two events, data get normalized. ([reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#submitting-a-form-formevents-pre-submit-formevents-submit-and-formevents-post-submit))

I would like to customize normalization step accorded to my FormType, and only thing ive found after few hours is file located at symfony/form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php which can be my problem. ([ArrayChoiceList on github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ChoiceType`, imho, is the wrong form type for this (and it's a common mistake), since it's used to select entries from a larger set of entries. Where usually order isn't important and non-selected entries are omitted.

Depending on what actually *is* selected, one in the following (not necessarily complete) list may serve you better:

#### A. entries are uniform

Usual use case for the [`CollectionType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). Leaving the default for the `CollectionType`'s options [`allow_add`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add) and [`allow_delete`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-delete) on `false` will prevent items from being added or removed. However, rendering might be more difficult. the `CollectionType`'s `entry_type` would probably be `ChoiceType` (with `multiple` set to `false`!) with probably similar choices as before ... or `CheckboxType`, however the values might be hard to set here.

#### B. entries are different

It might be better to manually add 9 form elements manually, and set the `property_path` of each to `recipe[N]` where `N` is a number between 0 and 8, defining where to get and where to set the specific value.

Comment: you're right, the closeness between the two types misled me, A. entirely solve my problem

Comment: @Awk_ glad I could help ;o)